# parse NMEA data using PATTERN MATCHER

Tags: java, android, parsing, pattern-matching, nmea

Been going crazy with ANDROID's regex using the pattern / matcher methods. I've been pretty unsuccessful for several days now. And yes I have been searching SO for help prior to asking for direct help. Ok, here's the deal: my incoming stream looks like this

Time in UTC (HhMmSs): 154653
Status (A=OK,V=KO): V
Latitude: 4428.2011
Direction (N/S): N
 
Longitude: 00440.5161
 
Direction (E/W): W
 
Speed in knots: 000.5
 
Direction in degrees: 342.8
 
Date in UTC (DdMmAa): 050407
 
Magnetic variation:
  
Variation (E/W):
  
Mode: A

All I want for now is the Latitude and Longitude values.

My code looks like this:

```
public class NmeaParser {
/**
 * Tag used for log messages
 */
public String nmeaData;
public String lat; //latitude
public String lon; //longitude

private static final String LOG_TAG = "NPGPS";



public String longitude, latitude;
//find the text pattern
public static final Pattern NMEA_PATTERN = Pattern.
            compile(
                    "\\d{6}" +
                    ":\\s\\D" +
                    "\\w+\\S\\s\\d{4}.\\d+" +
                    ":\\s\\D" +
                    "\\w+\\S\\s\\d{5}.\\d+" +
                    ":\\s\\D" +
                    "\\d{3}.\\d{1}" +
                    "\\d{3}.\\d{1}" +
                    "\\d{6}" +
                    ":\\s\\D" +
                    ":\\s\\D"
                    //".*" //this works as a test
                    );

public String parseNmeaSentence(String gpsSentence) {
        Matcher rmcMatcher = NMEA_PATTERN.matcher(gpsSentence);
        //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "dataNP: "+ rmcMatcher);
        if (rmcMatcher.find()) {
                //Log.d("Matcher", "PATTERN MATCHES!");
            //else
                //Log.d("MATCHER", "PATTERN DOES NOT MATCH!");
            //String time = rmcMatcher.group(1);
          latitude = rmcMatcher.group(3);
          nmeaData = latitude;

        }
            return nmeaData;
  }
}
```

and I keep getting these errors:

```
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at                 android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2058)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-17 11:37:36.936: E/AndroidRuntime(8756):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Clearly I'm screwing up with my regex syntax within the pattern / matcher methods.
Any help is clearly appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: Your error is about `ArrayAdapter` created with a resource that does not exist. Nothing to do with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your trace it appears that `android.widget.ArrayAdapter` is missing a resource in your code so this is the real issue why you can't proceed.

Re your regex, you don't have any [capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) in your regular expression and your pattern doesn't match your input string.

The best approach when using many expressions is to match up 1 or 2 expressions at a time to get those working first.

As you only wanted latitude & longitude, here is that regex code to get you (re-)started:

```
Pattern NMEA_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
                ".*Latitude: (\\d{4}.\\d+).*" + 
                "Longitude: (\\d{5}.\\d+).*");
Matcher m = NMEA_PATTERN.matcher(gpsSentence);

if (m.matches()) {
    String latitude = m.group(1);
    String longitude = m.group(2);
    ...
}
```

Comment: ok on the `android.widget.ArrayAdapter` I've been questioning that method of test. I'm using the BluetoothChat app heavily modified to just receive. Interesting that the parser "works" with the regex ".*" . I'm thinking that the pattern / matcher does not play well with the `android.widget.ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: The regex `.*` will match any every possible string but not much use for matching specific fields here. Are you always getting a chunk of data in the format above? If so, then regex will work to extract out the fields that you need.

Comment: Reimeus, thanks! I was using `.*` to perform a simple test of my methods and classes. After removing `android.widget.ArrayAdapter` from my code I was able to get the regex `\\d{4}.\\d{4}` working. It didn't like your original pattern...I like it because of the 4 vs 5 digits in the start of the lat & long. Currently `\\d{4}.\\d{4}` also matches the longitude. Ideas?

Comment: You could match it to a the number to a preceding `: ` pattern to frame the expression. I used `Latitude` and `Longitude` in the regex to frame the expression and also to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: I tested your code  again `".*Latitude: (\\d{4}.\\d+).*" +            "Longitude: (\\d{5}.\\d+).*"` just to be sure I had entered it correctly. This is the result: `09-20 06:37:19.760: I/GPSIN(16466): datainRM: null` so it's an endless series of NULL. I see your point about framing the regex I just don't see any other way except yours and I'm getting NULL. Hmmmmm...

Comment: ok looks like when I remove the leading & trailing `.*` it matches and starts dumping the numbers I want. Only issue is that what should be 1234.1234 ends up getting truncated at times to 1234.12 or 1234.1 or 1234.123 so I'm nearly there. Ideas? thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it is not matching correctly (obvious). If you're using my format above you could use `Latitude: (\\d+\\.\\d+).*Longitude: (\\d+\\.\\d+)`.